# Moving a WPF element (UserControl) to a new window in an MVVM safe way?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, mvvm, .net-4.5

A bit of a curious question I'm asking here I understand. But I have come across a scenario where it might be cool to have a "pop out to new window" feature. But the UI that the user is interacting with that time is technically a DataTemplate, it's just that I've used a UserControl as the template.

What I would like to do is just pop that UserControl out into a new window (without creating a new one). However if a new UI is created and isn't overly cumbersome then the binding rules should create an identical interface anyway.

My first thought was to simply take the item out of the view model's collection and insert it into a new one, this is where I'm thinking a new UI will be created, first question is then do I have to write a window manager now too?

Looking to see what some opinions and ideas would be as to how to approach this situation, if it's even possible.

PS. I would really like to avoid digging through the visual tree if possible, but I'm not against writing attached behaviors and such to do just that. I'm just unsure where to begin and what is the "best" approach and google isn't turning up anything relevant to my needs lol.

Thanks.

Comment: Moving WPF control into new window... why? Then what - put it back? I would better rethink my interface design if it causes me to do such things, because I suspect enormous time for debugging.

Comment: Well the user interface is very similar to that of an instant messenger. take Skype for instance, they have a "Compact" view which puts each message into it's own window separate from the contact list. Perhaps I would like to put the windows side-by-side like I do sometimes with Visual Studio solution files? Maybe I want to allow reordering like browser tabs? I don't understand what there is to re-think. It could be a handy feature for many editors....

Comment: I would just create another view and make sure that messages are virtualized so there aren't thousand of them in visual tree.

Answer (score 0):

I often move sections of XAML out of a bigger control into smaller controls, and it has the same basic requirements as moving a control into another window. As long as the `DataContext` of the window is correct, then the bindings in the control should still work.

Are you not overthinking it?

```
using System.Windows;

namespace WpfApplication1
{
    public partial class MyWindow : Window
    {
        // private, See Execute() instead
        MyWindow() {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        static public void Execute(MyViewModel vm)
        {
            MyWindow Window = new MyWindow() {
                DataContext = vm
            };

            Window.ShowDialog();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Well all of the ViewModel code is in it's own library (as it is growing quite extensive). The View is in an entirely different assembly This way is also not bindable